# E: Unable to locate package iwconfig in kali linux

Tags: package-management, kali-linux

Using kali-linux through **oracle virtual box** in **windows 8.1 os** .
While trying to install **iwconfig** for just learning purpose.getting **E: Unable to locate package iwconfig**

**/$ sudo apt-get update**

**/$ sudo apt-get install iwconfig**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package iwconfig
```

**$ dpkg -l wireless-tools && dpkg -L wireless-tools | grep iwconfig and ls /sbin/iw***

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-================================================
ii  wireless-tools 30~pre9-13.1 amd64        Tools for manipulating Linux Wireless Extensions
grep: and: No such file or directory
grep: ls: No such file or directory
Binary file /sbin/iwconfig matches
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Having read all the comments, my only input is `which iwconfig`. That should tell you where it is, if you do indeed have it installed.

Answer (score 1):

The command `iwconfig` is part of the `wireless-tools` package. You need to run

```
sudo apt install wireless-tools
```

Comment: /$ sudo apt install wireless-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
wireless-tools is already the newest version (30~pre9-13.1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libpulsedsp libwebrtc-audio-processing1 pulseaudio-utils rtkit
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1183 not upgraded.

Comment: the ouput for ` sudo apt install wireless-tools` command but still `sudo apt-get install iwconfig` shows `E: Unable to locate package iwconfig`

Comment: So it's already installed (probably as `/sbin/iwconfig`). There exists no package named `iwconfig`.

Comment: so `iwconfig` is installed but it is not there inside `/sbin`

Comment: how can I find where `iwconfig`  is installed?

Comment: For further debugging, please add to your question the output from the following commands: `dpkg -l wireless-tools && dpkg -L wireless-tools | grep iwconfig` and `ls /sbin/iw*`